# Java Swing Movement Stutter

Tags: java, swing

I'm experiencing stuttering while moving a block in Java Swing.

The following code will show the problem. When run, I'd like the box to move smoothly without any stuttering. Is there any way to achieve this in Swing? Or should I just move on to JavaFX?

MovementStutter.java

```
package movementstutter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MovementStutter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame win = new JFrame("Stutter Demo");
    win.getContentPane().add(new GamePanel());
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setResizable(false);
    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

GamePanel.java

```
package movementstutter;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

private boolean running;
private Thread thread;
private double x;
private double y;
private double movementFactor;

public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    setFocusable(true);
    grabFocus();
    movementFactor = 1;
    running = true;
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (running) {
        update();
        repaint();
        long sleep = 16 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        time += 16;
        if (sleep < 0) {
            sleep = 16;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void update() {
    if (x < 0) {
        movementFactor = 1;
    } else if (x > 608) {
        movementFactor = -1;
    }
    x += movementFactor * 200 * 0.016;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 32, 32);
}

}
```

Comment: You never update "time"

Comment: `200 * 0.016 == 3.5`...while possible, fractional updates "could" cause issues.  It'd suggest attempting to use `BufferStrategty`, which would allow you to take control of the painting process and keep the update and the paint within the same thread

Answer (score 1):

You are updating your swing component in a thread that is not the event-dispatch thread. You shouldn't do that. To perform timed actions, you can use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

For example, instead of implementing `Runnable`, make your panel implement `ActionListener`, remove the thread-related stuff, and add an action listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    update();
    repaint();
}
```

Then, in the panel's constructor, you can create a `Timer`. A `javax.swing.Timer` makes sure the action is performed in the event-dispatch loop. And it also simplifies the timing management:

```
public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    setFocusable(true);
    grabFocus();
    movementFactor = 1;
    running = true;
    new Timer(16,this).start();
}
```

If you need to stop the timer at any point, then you should assign it to a field, say

```
Timer blockTimer = new Timer(16,this);
```

And then you just do

```
blockTimer.start();
```

in your constructor, and you can have a button whose action includes

```
blockTimer.stop();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the same stuttering keeps occurring with this setup too. Is the stuttering unavoidable in Swing?

Comment: @noobcoder I don't see any stuttering on my side, to be honest. There was one when I ran your original program, but not when I changed to using a Timer. Are you trying it with this specific code or have you applied it to your *real* program?

Comment: That's interesting. I tried it with your specific code and experienced stuttering.

Could it be because I'm running it on NetBeans?

Comment: It could be a matter of hardware... How about: (a) don't use any double arithmetic, set everything to `int`, the factor to 4 and the timing to 20, which should give you the same speed. Graphics don't like floating point arithmetic. (b) Change the timer and the factor together, first to 8 for 40 milliseconds, then to 2 for 10 milliseconds. Any effect on the stuttering?

Comment: With all the different values, the stuttering still occurs - both on my laptop and my desktop PC.

Comment: I think this guy (https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/162266/simple-java-timer-lag-issue-caused-by-quad-core) was talking about the same issue. Seems like hardware makes a difference.

Comment: The comments there have a point: do a `repaint(x,y,width,height)` rather than just `repaint()`, remember to cover both the current square and the previous one.